# What to call a trait that has current utility but unclear evolutionary origin?

Tags: evolution, terminology, natural-selection, adaptation, fitness

I'm looking for a commonly used term to describe a trait that has clear current utility but an evolutionary origin that is uncertain and that we do not necessarily wish to emphasize in our description (e.g. to avoid unnecessary speculation):

- Adaptation emphasizes an origin driven by natural selection.
- Exaptation emphasizes an origin driven by co-option.
- "Aptation" fits the bill, but it seems cryptic and rarely used.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you give an example of such a trait? It's not clear to me what you are describing?

Comment: I have rephrased the question to make it more precise. A vast number of traits have some function but an uncertain evolutionary history (that we often do not wish to emphasize).

Comment: @kmm, maybe woman breasts? It's still unclear why are they prominent. But that's only if "being sexually succesful" counts as current utility.

Comment: Intelligent design.

Answer (score 2):

As you point out, people have sampled other terms like "aptation" but these terms are not commonly used.

In order to not imply anything about the evolutionary history, since it is unknown, I think it makes most sense to refer to these simply as **traits** or **phenotypes** (or genotype for that matter, depending on the approach you are taking). If you wish to emphasize that these traits are beneficial to the organism, it is sufficient to call them ***beneficial* traits** or use other adjectives like *useful*, *positive*, etc.